# Rclone is taking a long time

Tags: linux-mint, clone, cloud-storage

Sorry, Linux Mint's timeshift created a 7GB back up of 283,124 files. Timeshift used rsync to this end and it took about 10 minutes.

Since then I've been uploading my backup to google drive. It's been about 20 hours and I don't see that the files are being uploaded in any obvious order. I don't know if I should interrupt the process.

Is this typical? Should I take action? (By the way, can I rsync instead?)

The command that's been running is:

```
sudo rclone sync ~/a/timeshift google-drive://timeshift -vL
```

" ~/a " is just the source mount point. " goggle-drive " is rclones configured name for my google drive. rclone seems to be running and copying and outputting the filenames as well as periodical info such as

```
Transferred:   12.767 GBytes (192.341 kBytes/s)
Errors:                 0
Checks:                 0
Transferred:       144487
Elapsed time:  19h20m1.1s
Transferring:
 * .../lib/python3.7/test/test_tools/__init__.py: 100%     done, 0 Bytes/s, ETA: 0s
 * ...in/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/pic:  0% done, 0 Bytes/s, ETA: -
 * ...nclude/linux/platform_data/mmc-esdhc-imx.h: 100% done, 0 Bytes/s, ETA: 0s
 * ...t/usr/share/consolefonts/Lat2-VGA16.psf.gz: 100% done, 0 Bytes/s, ETA: 0s
```

Now 12GB is a lot more than the expected 7GB. Could rclone be looping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, syncing used up my whole allocated space and I cancelled it. The copying process seems to have been looping somehow. This may have to do with the specifics of the folder tree I'm uploading.

Possibly, carefully chosen mount point would suffice. Instead, I archived the backup into a single file.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're backing small files. Use the `--transfer` option to upload more of files simultaneously.

```
rclone sync /timeshift google-drive:timeshift --transfers 16
```

This will upload 16 at a time instead of 4.